# How to set up a Git repository server with SSH on Window OS

Tags: git, ssh

We have a small team and I want to setup git repository on my Windows OS in local network. So other team members can Clone/Pull/Push from their system in repository with SSH verification.

Comment: Install Gitlab runner on your Windows, https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html

Comment: Gitlab-runner is used to run jobs on windows and is of no use to host a git repository. Perhaps running https://gogs.io/ could be a good solution!